# MonetDB performance adding a new column into an existing table with thousen of columns

Tags: performance, monetdb

I need to add 100 columns into an existing table with 20000 columns in MonetDB, and each alter table command takes 10 seconds.

`ALTER TABLE [MYSCHEMA].[MYTABLE] ADD COLUMN [MYCOLUMN] [TYPE] NULL;` x100

The total process takes 1000 seconds to peform the addition. Is there any way to improve the operation?.

Thnks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `START TRANSACTION;` above the `ALTER TABLE` statements, and `COMMIT;` after.

In a somewhat smaller experiment where I add 10 columns to an existing 2000, the transaction makes it about 3× faster.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer; actually the program perform the operations on the same transaction.